# Is it possible to make a multisig transaction, where each signature is made separately(on top of other signatures)?

Tags: transactions, signature

I am trying to make a user sign a transaction on browser side, send the transaction to the backend, run some logic and then sign it with my wallet.
So the multisig process should run on different stages(not at once).